# Colocar projeto WS RESTful em produção

Tags: java, web-service, restful, jdbc, configuração

Sou iniciante em Java e esses negócios de .jar, .war, etc, são novidades para mim. Fiz meu primeiro projeto Webservice RESTful e adicionei 2 *.jars, o Gson e o JDBC.postgres.

Quero colocar em produção(num servidor que será **Tomcat**) para utilizá-lo a partir de outra(s) aplicação(ões). Como proceder?

É um projeto java web e contem apenas uma classe de conexão, um classe entidade e a classe webservice restful a partir do padrões. Foi desenvolvido no Netbeans 8.0. E não usei Maven, que aliás não sei o que é, como havia dito sou noob em java.

Comment: Seu projeto é de que tipo? Para facilitar as coisas, ele precisa ser um Dynamic Web Project. Está usando Maven?

Comment: Como assim "tipo"? É um projeto java web e contem apenas uma classe de conexão, um classe entidade e a classe webservice restful a partir do padrões. Foi desenvolvido no Netbeans 8.0. E não usei Maven, que aliás não sei o que é, como havia dito sou noob em java.

Comment: O processo para pôr em produção em um servidor de aplicação depende de qual você está usando. No seu caso, qual é? (Ex.: Glassfish, Tomcat, JBoss e etc..)

Comment: +Luídne, O servidor será Tomcat.

Comment: vai depender de seu servidor, temos vários tomcat, glasfish...

Comment: O processo também depende do serviço de hospedagem que você dispõe. Por exemplo, o processo do Jelastic difere de um em que se contrata um servidor dedicado. Que tipo de serviço você contratou?

Comment: Tá ficando difícil hein, hehehe... Tenho quase certeza que é dedicado. Não é meu, é de um colega que deixou usar para testar minhas aplicações.

Answer (score 1):

Cara, não sei se isso pode te ajudar, mas tem um tutorial onde eu explico como ter um projeto webservice (json) em um projeto java, utilizando o Maven.
O tutorial também explica como configurar o Tomcat e conexão no banco com o Hibernate (framework de acesso ao banco de dados que facilita muito essa comunicação).

O que é o Maven?

Uma breve explicação para te iniciar no conhecimento do que é o Maven, não vou entrar em muitos detalhes. Pensa que você precisa de um JAR no teu projeto, que é o teu caso, o Maven é responsável por baixar esse JAR para você e empacotar no teu projeto, ele roda os teus testes, gera o teu WAR, entre outras coisas que não vou aprofundar.

Começa pelo básico dele, é uma boa para você entrar no mundo Java, hoje o Maven é muito usado no mercado.

No teu caso como você está começando, pensa nele apenas para baixar os JARs e todas as dependências que o teu JAR precisa.

Segue: http://wp.me/p2DZEL-1Y

Comment: Muito obrigado +Fabio, ainda não li mas assim que eu ler darei um retorno.